# Img falls in background but it shouldn't

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to make a page, just for exercise, and I came up in a problem, so if you run the code the logo should be on top in center, than the menu centered under it.. but it falls in the background, help please
1. how to add a dropdown  under every three menu list items where I  can add some text, images and location

```css
body {
 background-color:lightgray;
 font-family: Tahoma, Cambria;
}
#header {
 height: 300px;
}
#logo {
 position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    top: 0; 
}
#menu {
 position: relative;
 max-height:60px;
 font-family: Cambria;
 font-style: bold, italic;
 text-align: center;
}

#menu ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float:none;
}

#menu li a {
 display:inline-block;
 color:#009CFF;
 padding: 10px 200px;
 overflow:hidden;
 transition: 0.3s;
 font-style:italic;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration:none;
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: dimgray;
    color: deepskyblue;
}

body {
 border: 2px solid dark-gray ;
}
l>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <img src = "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id = "logo" alt = "Antomatik logo"/> 
  </header>
  <div id = "menu">
    <ul>
     <li class="onama">
      <a href="antomatik/onama.html">O nama</a></li>
     <li class="povijest">
      <a href="antomatik/povijest.html">Povijest</a></li>
     <li class="kontakt">
      <a href="antomatik/kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    
    </ul>
  </div>
  <footer>
  
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a placeholder or lorempixel image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `header`, not `#header`

```css
body {
 background-color:lightgray;
 font-family: Tahoma, Cambria;
}
header {
 height: 100px;
}
#logo {
 position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    top: 0; 
}
#menu {
 position: relative;
 max-height:60px;
 font-family: Cambria;
 font-style: bold, italic;
 text-align: center;
}

#menu ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float:none;
}

#menu li a {
 display:inline-block;
 color:#009CFF;
 padding: 10px 200px;
 overflow:hidden;
 transition: 0.3s;
 font-style:italic;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration:none;
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: dimgray;
    color: deepskyblue;
}

body {
 border: 2px solid dark-gray ;
}
l>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x100" id = "logo" alt = "Antomatik logo"/> 
  </header>
  <div id = "menu">
    <ul>
     <li class="onama">
      <a href="antomatik/onama.html">O nama</a></li>
     <li class="povijest">
      <a href="antomatik/povijest.html">Povijest</a></li>
     <li class="kontakt">
      <a href="antomatik/kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    
    </ul>
  </div>
  <footer>
  
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```